# Cycle through an array

Tags: java, loops, testing

lets say you have an array that has the days of the week in it:

```
String days[]={"monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday",
               "friday","saturday","sunday"};
```

Now lets say you have a array that keeps track of every number day of the year with an array
made up of 366 elements.(1 extra for leap year).

Is it possible to write a loop or something that when done cycling through the days array, that it resets back to monday to keep so that the output looks something like:

Monday:1
Tuesday:2
Wednesday:3
Thursday:4
Friday:5
Saturday:6
Sunday:7
Monday:8
Tuesday:9
ect all the way to 366

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the modulo operator `(%)`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 366; i++) {
    System.out.format("%s:%d%n", days[(i - 1) % days.length], i);
}
```

Comment: Nice I don't use the modulo operator enough to understand when exactly to use it. To me it's something taught once, but never really implemented.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operation

```
int[] year = new int[366];

for(int i = 0 ; i < year.length ; i++) { // initialize the days
    year[i] = i;
}

String[] days = {"monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday",
               "friday","saturday","sunday"};

for(int i = 0; i < year.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(days[i % (days.length)] + ":" + year[i]);
}
```

yields
monday:0
tuesday:1
wednesday:2
thursday:3
friday:4
saturday:5
sunday:6
monday:7
tuesday:8
wednesday:9...